# Return empty fields instead of null on an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, null

this is my query:

```
SELECT u.fname fname, u.lname lname, r.fname inviter_f, r.lname inviter_l 
FROM guests u 
  LEFT JOIN guests r ON u.inviter_id = r.guest_id 
where u.wedding_id=10
```

how do I return empty values instead of NULL?
At the current query if inviter_id = 0 it returns it inviter_f and inviter_l as NULL

Thank you super hero's!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()` function.

```
SELECT 
   u.fname fname, 
   u.lname lname, 
   coalesce(r.fname,'') inviter_f, 
   coalesce(r.lname, '') inviter_l 
FROM guests u 
  LEFT JOIN guests r ON u.inviter_id = r.guest_id 
where u.wedding_id=10
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 1):

Use `IFNULL` function, [have a look at the documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
SELECT u.fname fname, u.lname lname, 
IFNULL(r.fname, '') AS inviter_f,
IFNULL(r.lname, '') AS inviter_l 
FROM guests u 
  LEFT JOIN guests r ON u.inviter_id = r.guest_id 
where u.wedding_id=10
```